# How to install ffmpeg through yum

Tags: ffmpeg, yum

Anyone knows the trick?

And how to install ffmpeg ? `yum install mpeg` only returns this:

```
======================================================================================== Matched: mpeg ========================================================================================
libiec61883.i386 : Streaming library for IEEE1394
libiec61883.x86_64 : Streaming library for IEEE1394
qffmpeg-devel.i386 : Development package for qffmpeg
qffmpeg-devel.x86_64 : Development package for qffmpeg
qffmpeg-libs.i386 : Libraries for qffmpeg
qffmpeg-libs.x86_64 : Libraries for qffmpeg
```

Comment: Maybe try superuser.com?

Answer (score 2):

ffmpeg -- and other multimedia tools -- is available through the [rpmfusion](http://rpmfusion.org/) repository.  Instructions for configuring your system to use rpmfusion are available [here](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration).

Comment: How to switch back the repository afterwards?

Comment: You don't need to "switch back" the repository.  Your system can use multiple repositories.  If you don't want it enabled by default, you can set "enabled=0" in the repository configuration and then use it explicitly with something like "yum --enablerepo=rpmfusion"  on the command line.